# Type Check Failure on upgrade to PrimeNG v16 and TypeScript 5

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

I have a PrimeNG `p-tree` component that is failing on the following binding:

```
[(selection)]="selectedTreeNode"
```

`selectedTreeNode` is:

```
selectedTreeNode: CallFlowTreeNode | null = null;
```

`CallFlowTreeNode` extends PrimeNG's TreeNode:

```
export interface CallFlowTreeNode extends TreeNode {
  custom?: string;
  someNum?: number;
}
```

`TreeNode` is an interface:

```
export interface TreeNode<T = any> { ... }
```

So why am I getting this?

> Type 'TreeNode | TreeNode[] | null' is not assignable to
> type 'CallFlowTreeNode | null'.   Type 'TreeNode[]' has no
> properties in common with type 'CallFlowTreeNode'.ngtsc(2322)

What am I not seeing here with the type system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message you're seeing indicates a type mismatch. specifically states that the type `TreeNode[]` (an array of `TreeNode`) does not have properties in common with the `CallFlowTreeNode` interface.

To fix the issue, update the type declaration of `selectedTreeNode` to:

```
selectedTreeNode: CallFlowTreeNode | CallFlowTreeNode[] | null = null;
```

Comment: Better than GTP-4 did ... thanks.